# Spring Boot Oauth2 Client Display profile Photo or Picture of social Facebook login Problem?

Tags: spring-boot, facebook-login

Hi I am using spring boot oauth2 client for Facebook Login for my Spring Boot project, FaceBooking login is working fine and I can get name and email address too, but I can not catch the photo url properly. I debugged and I see, I have profile picture in the channel, but it is at an array or something. Please look:

```
Name: [373860275vbvb2878377831], Granted Authorities: [[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_public_profile]], User Attributes: [{id=3738602752878331, name=David Mark, email=abc545@gmail.com, picture={data={height=50, is_silhouette=false, url=https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=3738602675265656878331&height=50&width=50&ext=1591440697&hash=AeQTuuV0tn-GHQDV, width=50}}}]
```

I am using `maps.put("fbphoto", principal.getAttribute("picture"));`

I only need url of the photo. But How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue using ajax at front-end and I have called the json like

```
data.picture.data.url
```

But I need to solve it at back-end, then I can send picture url at front-end display for facebook, Google and Github too.

How to get only ORL in a String variable?